# kendo ui mvc grid editortemplate issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-interface, grid, kendo-ui

What I am trying to do :

1. I have a form with Kendo UI controls like DatePicker(s), Dropdownlist(s), NumericTextBox(s) on the first half of the page
2. Second half has a Kendo UI MVC Grid control

   - This Kendo UI Grid control has 8 columns in which 2 columns has a Kendo dropdownlist(EditorTemplate) and CheckBox(EditorTemplate).
   - The Kendo UI Grid control is Ajax binding.
3. When the save button is clicked, all the values from the Kendo UI controls(first half) and Kendo UI grid control(second half) together are posted as a Json object via "Ajax Post" to the controller.
4. I am using Model binding for the above process

Issues or the problem I am facing :

The first half of the form with other Kendo UI controls are posting their values properly to the controller, but where as the Kendo UI Grid is having some problems posting some column values

- The columns in the Kendo UI Grid with the datatype decimal is not posting the values
- The EditorTemplate controls like the CheckBox and the kendo dropdown when selected  shows the values `"[Object Object]"` for dropdownlist and the actual value of the boolean rather than the checkbox control.

Comment: No code means almost no chance for help.

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Products).Name("Products").Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
.Columns(columns => { columns.Bound(p => p.Chk).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' ${ Chk == true ? checked='checked' : ''} disabled />");
columns.Bound(p => p.Account).EditorTemplateName("AccountList"); columns.Bound(p => p.ProductID).Hidden(); 
columns.Bound(p => p.Adjustment).Format("{0:C}"); columns.Bound(p => p.NewBalance).Format("{0:C}"); })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax().Model(model => { model.Id(p => p.ProductID); }).ServerOperation(false)))

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
  $("#btnSaveD").click(function () {
        var GdSrc = $("#Products").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
        var ViewObj = { //other form data,
      Products: GdSrc };
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Save","Home")',data: JSON.stringify(ViewObj),
datatype: "JSON",contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
type: 'POST',
success: function (result) {
$("#Products").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
alert('Form Details has been saved'); },
        }); return false; );
 });
</script>

Comment: This is the EditorTemplate code:
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
.Name("Account").DataTextField("Text")
.DataValueField("Value").BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
    new SelectListItem() {
        Text = "Inv Type1", Value = "1"
    },
    new SelectListItem() {
        Text = "Inv Type2", Value = "2" 
    }
    })
    .OptionLabel("Select")
    .SelectedIndex(0)

Comment: public class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public bool Chk { get; set; }
        public double Balance { get; set; }
        public double Deposit { get; set; }
        public double Adjustment { get; set; }
        public double NewBalance { get; set; }
        [UIHint("AccountList"), Required]
        public string Account { get; set; }
    }

Comment: public class Category
{
 public int CategoryID { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public string Address { get; set; }
 public string Address1 { get; set; }
 public System.DateTime Date1 { get; set; }
 public System.DateTime Date2 { get; set; }
 public string ListA { get; set; }
 public string ListB { get; set; }
 public string ListC { get; set; }
 public int Count { get; set; }
 public decimal Price { get; set; }
 public decimal Amount { get; set; }
 public bool decision { get; set; }
 public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt you want the Grid as part of the Form.  Typically the Grid interacts via ajax and not via a batch Form submit with other controls - unwrap it from the Form.  This alone may save you a headache.

1st Half:

Try to use Kendo().DatePickerFor(), Kendo().DropDownListFor(), etc.  You do not need to explicitly name these Kendo controls via .Name().  This will help you with the model binding.

2nd Half:

Use another data type other than decimal.  You think that is tough?  Try using a TimeSpan type for time-of-day with no date attached (grown men cry).

You do not need, typically, an EditorTemplate for boolean/checkboxes.  Just use this trick (asuming your are using Razor, since you left no code).

```
columns.Bound(b => b.IsActive).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' ${ IsActive == true ? checked='checked' : ''} disabled />");
```

Your best bet for your Grid DDLs is

```
columns.ForeignKey(b => b.CustodianIdPrimary, Model.Custodians, "Id", "FullName").EditorViewData(new {ProjectId = Model.ProjectId}).EditorTemplateName("CustodianDropDownList");
```

Where the Model.Custodians is a List of all possible items.  You can then bind your EditorTemplate to this List, or make an ajax call to populate if you need a subset in this particular DDL, like this

```
@model int
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(""))
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .DataTextField("FullName")
    .OptionLabel("Unassigned")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read.Action("ReadProjectCustodiansDdl", "SysMaint", new {projectId = ViewData["ProjectId"]}))
    )
)
```

But here is the Kendo supplied example

```
@model object       
@(
    Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)        
        .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData[ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("") + "_Data"])
)
```

Note the use of the EditorViewData parameter in my initial columns.ForeignKey, that is used in this eample to pass the whole list.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answers Trey, really appreciate that, but here is my points:- 1) As I mentioned, the requirement is to save the form data(other kendo ui controls) along with the grid data as a ajax posting.2)This means that the grid will not be having editor toolbar (no CRUD operations inside the grid).3) And also,inside my grid there has to be some calculations and validation which should happen when one of the cell value(s) are changed.4)For this I am planning to refresh grid datasource which will update the columns and footer dynamically on the clientside and when saved,will save as batch.

Comment: One more point to add is: 1) I am rendering the grid(2nd half) as a partial view

Comment: Hi Trey, I actually do have a scenario where I want the grid to postback with the rest of the form because the whole page needs to be saved in a transaction (modified grid rows included). Is there a way to get all the dirty data from the grid on postback and no ajax at all?

Comment: I am a grown man crying over trying to edit a TimeSpan representing the time of day. I tried mapping it to a `DateTime` in my view model and only using the time part in the format. All fine until editing.

Comment: You are so right about the TimeSpan :D I ended up creating a DateTime wrapper property like `DateTime Date { get { return new DateTime(Time.Ticks); } set { Time = value.TimeOfDay; } }`

Comment: The editor template for the checkbox is awesome.  I've been trying to get that working for a long time and that works perfectly.