# Kendo UI DropDownListFor html wrapper - How to set up the BindTo to a collection in model? Rather than ViewData or Viewbag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm learning about Kendo UI. We're moving towards using Kendo UI for everything in the views of our MVC apps.

I am attempting to bind to a collection that's within the model object that is in each row for the Kendo Grid. We are using an EditorTemplate to achieve the dropdown, which has worked for several more simple examples.

In this case however, we are attempting to make the source of this dropdown menu filtered by the value of property in that object.

**Model object:**

```
public class AppRolesForUserVM
{
    public int AppId { get; set; }
    public string appName { get; set; }
    public AppRole appRole { get; set; }
    public AppUser appUser { get; set; }
    public List<AppRole> appRolesList { get; set; }
```

}

**Snippet from the grid:**

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<AppRolesForUserVM>()
              .Name("ApplicationGrid")
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(p => p.AppId).Title("Application Id").Width(50);
                  columns.Bound(p => p.appName).Title("Application Name").Width(100);                    
                  columns.Bound(p => p.appRole.Id).ClientTemplate("#=appRole.Name#").EditorTemplateName("AppRolesForUser").Title("AppRole").Width(100);  // *****
```

The last column in the above code is where we've been attempting to implement this drop down menu. It refers to editorTemplateName AppRolesForUser which is below:

**AppRolesForUser EditorTemplate:**

```
@model AdminAuthorization.Models.ViewModels.AppRolesForUserVM

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(p => p.appRole.Id)
    .Name("appRole.Id")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .BindTo((IEnumerable)ViewData["ListOfRoles"]) // ***** 
)
```

Where I've marked **** is where I'm hoping to figure out how to make this actually pull data based on an input parameter from the model object AppRolesForUserVM... Passing the appId property to get a list of roles for that application... Simple enough right?

With the way I have it set up now, the dropdown list shows after you select the Edit button, but the dropdown list is empty! Link to image of dropdown with nothing in it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEcMw.png

I've been attempting to change the BindTo within the editortemplate to refer to Model.appRolesList, but every time I get null pointer exceptions because I guess the model isn't being passed to this dropdownlistFor helper? Not sure...

My team has been a little stumped on how to implement this functionality. We're all fairly new to using Kendo, and thus there are no experts in the group when it comes to the ins and outs of these types of circumstances.

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read this! :)

EDIT: it seems like the foreign key method will be the best way to implement this functionality,  but I'm running into issues trying to reference the collection from the foreign key html wrapper. I'll post another code snippet when I'm back at my desk

**EDIT 2 with code snippet:**

This is the updated grid to use just a .ForeignKey reference instead of the .Bound. In this example I'm still struggling to reference the list of objects within the AppRolesForUserVM object... Might anybody have the syntax to do so? Most of the examples I've seen in the Kendo Demos are fairly simple where they refer to a collection stored in ViewData or ViewBag.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<AppRolesForUserVM>()
                  .Name("ApplicationGrid")
                  .Columns(columns =>
                  {
                      columns.Bound(p => p.AppId).Title("Application Id").Width(50);
                      columns.Bound(p => p.appName).Title("Application Name").Width(100);
                      columns.ForeignKey(p => p.appRole.Id, q.appRolesList).ClientTemplate("#=appRole.Name#").Title("App Role").Width(100);
```

Comment: Do you have a `ViewData` item named `"ListOfRoles"`? Your model shows you have a property `List<AppRole> appRolesList` which I assume is what you want to display for the options?

Comment: doesn't the ForeignKey column type allow you to specify the dataSource.. why not use it?  http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/foreignkeycolumn

Comment: Jamied77, I was not aware of that feature, thank you! :) ... Stephen,  yes using the appRolesList is the plan. My view model already has the filtered list contained within appRolesList,  so hopefully pointing to that within the model object of the editor template could be feasible?  When attempting to plug in that value is where I ran into null pointer exceptions.  8^/

Comment: Then would it not be `.BindTo(p => p.appRolesList)`?

Comment: I'll be trying that syntax when I get back to the office.  Thank you Stephen!

Comment: Seems like that lambda expression syntax isn't something the http compiler is happy with: error CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Kendo.Mvc.UI.DropDownListItem>' because it is not a delegate type"}

Comment: JamieD77, when setting up a ForeignKey column do you know the syntax that I could use to refer to a collection within the model object of the row? The linked example uses ViewData, which could be OK but in this case the dropdown menu will have different contents on a row-by-row basis; so I will not be able to use ViewData for this as I'm not sure how I'd set up a bunch of ViewData collections one per row, you know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done this with an EditorTemplate, but another option is to make a controller action that returns roles and use it:

```
public JsonResult ReadRoles(int id)
{
    var roleList = context.Roles.Where(r => r.AppId == id).OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToSelectList(r => r.Id.ToString(), r => r.Name);
    var result = Json(roleList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return result;
}
```

Then your drop down becomes something like:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(p => p.appRole.Id)
    .Name("appRole.Id")
    .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("ReadRoles", "App", new { id = @Model.AppId })
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .HtmlAttributes(new {data_value_primitive = "true"})
)
```

where App is the controller you put the read action into and ToSelectList is an extension method we wrote to create an IEnumerable.

***EDIT with the final approach I was able to use to get this working:*** I have gotten this working and it is using a similar approach to what was in this answer, just slightly tweaked.

The dropdown editortemplate code I'm using now is:

```
@model Project.Models.ViewModels.AppRolesForUserVM

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(p => p.appRole.Id)
    .Name("appRole.Id")
    .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("ReadRoles", "App").Data("onRead")))
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { data_value_primitive = "true" })
)
```

The .Data("onRead") in the data source declaration calls the following function, which gets the data row being edited and then gets the value from the first column in that row; which contains the ID I want to pass to my controller's read action:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onRead(e) {
            var row = $(event.currentTarget).find(".k-grid-edit-row");
            var id = row.find("td:first").html();
            return { id: id };
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a try!! Thank you for reading through this question and proposing an answer. I think this one might just be the ticket...

Comment: Seems like referring to the model isn't going to work, as apparently the Model is not passed to the editor template, but is only used for metadata as per: http://www.telerik.com/forums/pass-additional-data-to-read-method-of-datasource. This same link offers the alternative of using a small javascript method to pass a value from the grid. It seems like that's promising, now I'm implementing the syntax to get the parent object and then the ID field from that object. Apparently Kendo Grid doesn't set up ID or name of the object by default, so I had to accomplish that via htmlattributes.

Comment: Take a look at EditorViewData here http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/GridBoundColumnBuilder and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964838/kendo-ui-mvc-grid-editortemplate-issue

Comment: Steve Greene, I really appreciate your follow up! I am going to give this a shot this afternoon and see what I can do. Happy Friday! :)

Comment: This approach, combined with the .Data("javascript_method") syntax defined in link: http://www.telerik.com/forums/pass-additional-data-to-read-method-of-datasource seems to be meeting my need conceptually. Now I just need to get my jquery selector syntax sorted out for getting an ID out of the row this is being called from. Might create a new question on here for that one... Thank you, Steve Greene!    I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: OK! I finally got this working. The jquery I used to get the value for that Data method was: function onRead(e) { var row = $(event.currentTarget).find(".k-grid-edit-row"); var id = row.find("td:first").html(); return { id: id }; } I hope this helps someone else if they run into this problem! Thanks again Steve Greene! :)